# Как отправлять форму?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть пошаговая форма, которая отправляется так:

```js
onFinished: onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
  $.post('mail-attach.php', $('#signup-form').serialize(), function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); 
  });
  }
```

Проблема в том, что при таком варианте из формы отправляется только текст без вложений (фото), я так понимаю это из-за serialize. Как сделать отправку с вложениями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'mail-attach.php',
    data: new FormData($('#signup-form')[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       //process data
       alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); 
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       //process error msg
    },
});
```

Comment: ошибка: http://prntscr.com/revi3s

Comment: @АлександрКоновалов, загружай картинки через механизм SO.

Comment: @Igor, да, работает, спасибо! Я попробовал добавить сообщение на успешную отправку(http://prntscr.com/revw83), но оно не вызывается почему-то. В чем проблемка? На других формах работает

Comment: @АлександрКоновалов По такому количеству кода это нельзя определить. Не вызывается ни `success`, ни `error`?

Comment: @Igor именно. С input submit вызывается, а так не хочет (кнопка через <a>)

Comment: @Igor Вот с такого кода вызывается (для button submit)
http://prntscr.com/rexckc

Comment: @Igor Может, кнопку переделать из a в button?

Comment: @АлександрКоновалов Может, у Вас страница перезаружается?

Comment: @Igor нет, не перезагружается

Comment: @Igor, добавил $("#signup-form").submit(); и заработало!